# How to customize migration generation in EF Core Code First?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

There is a special base table type in my `DbContext`. And when inherited from it I need to generate an additional "SQL" migration operation to create a specific trigger for it. It makes sure table structure is consistent by checking overlapped ranges. Since there are no overlapping indexes or check constraints in SQL Server I have to use triggers (using functions in check constraints leads to same problems with migrations along with cluttering functions "namespace" in SQL).

Since I haven't found any way to create triggers during `OnModelCreating` I thought of altering generated migrations. But how to do that?

Tried using `SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator` and `SqlServerMigrationsAnnotationProvider`, but as their name suggests they are used only on a final stage, during generation of SQL commands. This makes them a bit "hidden" from sight when using migrations. Hard to customize when needed and maintain afterwards.

Thought about using `CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator` which seems to be perfect for my needs. But there is a problem - I can't access this class. Nor it's namespace.

According to source this class resides in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design` namespace and is public. And in order to access it a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` package has to be installed.

But it doesn't work.

What am I missing here? How to access and inherit this class? Or perhaps there is a much better and proper way to create triggers automatically during migrations for specific tables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How to provide your own `ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator` implementation

> Thought about using CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator which seems to be perfect for my needs. But there is a problem - I can't access this class. Nor it's namespace.
>
> According to source this class resides in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design namespace and is public. And in order to access it a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package has to be installed.
>
> But it doesn't work.
>
> What am I missing here? **How to access and inherit this class?**

Let's assume you are calling the following CLI command to add a new migration at design time:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "SomeMigration"
```

Here is a fully working sample console program, that will use a custom `ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator` implementation called `MyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator`, inherited from `CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator`:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class MyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator : CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator
    {
        public MyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator(CSharpMigrationOperationGeneratorDependencies dependencies)
            : base(dependencies)
        {
        }

        protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n---\r\nMyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator was used\r\n---\r\n");
            base.Generate(operation, builder);
        }
    }
    
    public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
    {
        public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
            => services.AddSingleton<ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator, MyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator>();
    }
    
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63575132")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The `MyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator` class outputs the following lines for every added table as prove that it was called:

```cs
---
MyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator was used
---
```

As @KasbolatKumakhov pointed out in his comment, it should also be mentinued that the way for referencing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` [has been changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#microsoftentityframeworkcoredesign-is-now-a-developmentdependency-package) from 2.2. to 3.0:

> Starting with EF Core 3.0, it is a DevelopmentDependency package. This means that the dependency won't flow transitively into other projects, and that you can no longer, by default, reference its assembly.
> [...]
> If you need to reference this package to override EF Core's design-time behavior, then you can update PackageReference item metadata in your project.
>
> ```xml
> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0">
>   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
>   <!-- Remove IncludeAssets to allow compiling against the assembly -->
>   <!--<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>-->
> </PackageReference>
> ```

### How to properly implement an additional `MigrationOperation` (e.g. for trigger creation)

> Since I haven't found any way to create triggers during OnModelCreating I thought of altering generated migrations. But how to do that?

To do this properly, you would need to do the following:

- Add your own annotation to the tables in question (e.g. `MyPrefix:Trigger`)
- Implement your own `MigrationOperation` (e.g. `CreateTriggerMigrationOperation`)
- Provide your own `IMigrationsModelDiffer` implementation (derived from `MigrationsModelDiffer`; this is internal) that returns your own `MigrationOperation`
- Provide your own `ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator` implementation (derived from `CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator`), that then generates the C# code for your own `MigrationOperation`
- Provide your own `IMigrationsSqlGenerator` implementation (derived from  `SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator`) that then handles translating your own `MigrationOperation` to SQL

Comment: Thanks. How do you register MyDesignTimeServices, so MyCSharpMigrationOperationGenerator get's called?

Comment: You don't. It is being discovered using reflection by the EF Core tools. The sample code I posted is complete and should just run as is. It does not register `MyDesignTimeServices` anywhere. See [Design-time services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/services) for further information. This works for all the command line tools (at _design time_). If you would want to apply migrations at _runtime_, you would need to register `ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator` in your DI container (and would not need an `IDesignTimeServices` implementation at all).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It seems I can't edit your post, so could you please add this link to it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#dip) ? This explains how to access the mentioned class in 3.x

Comment: @KasbolatKumakhov Good point! I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I would generally not recommend to implement this solution. You tie your application with design time features. The assembly with the namespace EntityFrameworkCore.Design is intended for the CLI ef core tool which creates the csharp migration code. The assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' will fail to load in hosting environments (for example when hosted in IIS - Startup error 500.30). I post an alternative solution to generate trigger.

Comment: @DiegoFrehner Well it really depends on your scenario. The implementation I posted code for is not supposed to work with IIS. It uses `ConfigureDesignTimeServices` which is directed at being run from the console via `dotnet ef`. It also specifically addresses the way that the OP wanted to solve the problem. That being said, I did outline the proper way to implement another migration operation in `How to properly implement an additional MigrationOperation (e.g. for trigger creation)`. If anybody needs actual code for that, I am happy to provide some.

Comment: Also as a general comment, for real-life production apps, never apply migrations through your app. This is heavily discouraged by me and also the EF Core team. Always generate scripts from your migrations, validate them, run them against a test database, and then manually apply them to the production database (after taking backups first).

Comment: I know that it should be run from the console not from IIS (since it is a design time feature). The problem is the introduced reference into the project of the DbContext. As soon as sth tries to resolve all types of the assembly at runtime (ex. AutoMapper), then an exception occurs. I think the OP goal is to create trigger for certain model types. The ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator seemed a promising way to him but no more. I do not understand how a proper implementation can include ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator mixed into the DbContext Assembly. Nevertheless your post helped a lot.

Comment: Another documented way is to write custom MigrationOperation. But with the (documented) MigrationSqlGenerator you can only convert Custom MigrationOperation into sql. You would still have to write manually the migration step. The problem is without ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator  you can not generate the migration itself. The only way i see too automate migration step creation is the solution i provided as an additional answer.

Comment: Maybe the problem is my project setup, where i have the DbContext in the same assembly which is later the startup project. Somehow you have to separate the "tool" with ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator from the actual application. You know my goal was to add or remove some attributes to model classes, hit Add-Migration in the console and then migration step appears. Thats why IDesignTimeServices ends up in the same assembly.

Comment: In my project I have separate assemblies: IAppDbContextContract (with just the DbSets), AppDbContext (which is inherited from DbContext and IAppDbContextContract) and MigrationAssembly, which consumes both. The latter is used to apply migrations and never leaves IDE.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I think a little explanation about what's going on would be good. The generate method never gets called for me, maybe has something to do with the DesignTimeService.

Comment: @Bamdad The code should work flawlessly. You didn't describe what steps you took. Did you run the code exactly as I posted it? Did you run the `dotnet ef migrations add "SomeMigration"` command? Are there any error messages when you run the command? About describing what is going on: This is all very advanced stuff here. It would take me too much time to give an adequate explanation of everything involved and why it works. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask. Otherwise, please take a look at the EF Core source code or the docs (e.g. about `IDesignTimeServices`).

Comment: I also overrided `GetNamespaces` in `CSharpMigrationsGenerator` to add the namespaces for my custom `MigrationOperation` as well to add the namespace of the extension method that is being used for that custom `MigrationOperation`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but it does the similar job with low cost and it may come handy for someone.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;

public static class MigrationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigForOracle(this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        //For each table registered in the builder, let's create a sequence and a trigger
        foreach (CreateTableOperation createTableOperation in migrationBuilder.Operations.ToArray().OfType<CreateTableOperation>())
        {
            string tableName = createTableOperation.Name;
            string primaryKey = createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.Columns[0];
            migrationBuilder.CreateSequence<int>(name: $"SQ_{tableName}", schema: createTableOperation.Schema);
            migrationBuilder.Sql($@"CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ""TR_{tableName}""
                                    BEFORE INSERT ON ""{tableName}""
                                    FOR EACH ROW
                                    WHEN (new.""{primaryKey}"" IS NULL)
                                    BEGIN
                                        SELECT ""SQ_{tableName}"".NEXTVAL
                                        INTO   :new.""{primaryKey}""
                                        FROM   dual;
                                    END;");
        }
    }
}
```

You can do whatever you want in the extension method and then call it at the end of the `Migration.Up()` method. I use it to create sequences and triggers for Oracle 11g tables for identifier increment.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not intended to modify the ef core csharp code generation.
But to generate custom migration statements (in my case triggers) i do following (shortened to relevant) using SqlOperation.

Implement a ModelDiffer

```
public class MyMigrationsModelDiffer : MigrationsModelDiffer {

  public MyMigrationsModelDiffer(IRelationalTypeMappingSource typeMappingSource,
    IMigrationsAnnotationProvider migrationsAnnotations,
    IChangeDetector changeDetector,
    IUpdateAdapterFactory updateAdapterFactory,
    CommandBatchPreparerDependencies commandBatchPreparerDependencies)
    : base(typeMappingSource, migrationsAnnotations, changeDetector, updateAdapterFactory, commandBatchPreparerDependencies) { }

  protected override IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> Diff(IModel source, IModel target, DiffContext diffContext) {
    return base.Diff(source, target, diffContext).Concat(GetTriggerTriggerDifferences(source, target));
  }

  public override Boolean HasDifferences(IModel source, IModel target) {
    return base.HasDifferences(source, target) || HasTriggerAnnotationDifferences(source, target);
  }

  public IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> GetTriggerTriggerDifferences(IModel source, IModel target) {
    if (source == null || target == null) {
      return new new List<MigrationOperation>(0);
    }

    Dictionary<String, IAnnotation> triggerAnnotationPerEntity = new Dictionary<String, IAnnotation>();
    foreach (var entityType in source.GetEntityTypes()) {
      triggerAnnotationPerEntity[entityType.Name] = GetTableAnnotation(entityType);
    }
    var operations = new List<MigrationOperation>();
    foreach (var entityType in target.GetEntityTypes()) {
      triggerAnnotationPerEntity.TryGetValue(entityType.Name, out IAnnotation sourceTriggerTable);
      IAnnotation targetTriggerTable = GetTableAnnotation(entityType);

      if (targetTriggerTable?.Value == sourceTriggerTable?.Value) {
        continue;
      }

      Boolean isCreate = targetTriggerTable != null;
      String tableName = (entityType as EntityType)?.GetTableName();
      String primaryKey = entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties[0].Name;
      if (isCreate) {
        SqlOperation sqlOperation = new SqlOperation();
        sqlOperation.Sql = $@"CREATE TRIGGER...";
        operations.Add(sqlOperation);
      }
      else {
        // drop trigger sqloperation
      }
    }
    return operations;
  }

  private static IAnnotation GetTableAnnotation(IEntityType entityType) {
    return entityType.GetAnnotations()?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "WantTrigger");
  }

  public Boolean HasTriggerAnnotationDifferences(IModel source, IModel target) {
    return GetTriggerTriggerDifferences(source, target).Any();
  }
}
```

Replace the model differ in your DbContext

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
  base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
  if (optionsBuilder == null) {
    return;
  }
  optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsModelDiffer, MyMigrationsModelDiffer>();
}
```

Mark the desired Models with an annotation.

```
builder.Entity<MyTable>().HasAnnotation("WantTrigger", "1.0");
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal was to supply a user with a full migration step, in which all operations are visible prior generating SQL scripts. So any changes could be made and tested beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Open your migration file and make changes to your `Up` method.

Then apply the migration using `Update-Database` from package manager console.

Something like this:

```
public partial class CreateDatabase : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("Some custom SQL statement");
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Authors",
            columns: table => new
            {
                AuthorId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Authors", x => x.AuthorId);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what i'm after. I need an automatic way to do the exact same things, because it will be very hard to track each table which is used in migrations. The SQL statements has to be added only when specific tables are created. Not every time.