# Customizing a Migration File

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

this is my very first post.

Does anyone know how to add text to an EF Migration File?
Specifically, I would like to add this text:

```
var sqlFile = Path.Combine("Scripts/CustomScript.Sql"); 
migrationBuilder.Sql(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));
```

to the bottom of:

```
public partial class MyMigration : Migration
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
```

in all migration files all the time

I don't mean by editing the generated file but by some dynamic mechanism so that there are no extra steps in performing this action: "dotnet ef database update --context MyAppContext"

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.4" />
```

(I am using the latest (11.05.2022) VS2022 console template with .NET6 syntax)
I have tried all the suggestions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575132/how-to-customize-migration-generation-in-ef-core-code-first/72203122#72203122) but none work in the newest .NET code versions.

I am new to StackOverflow and appreciate any and all positive feedback. TY

Comment: hi all, its been a month with no new views ... is this really an unsolvable issue?

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a partial class, you can create a new partial class in a different file or directory with the same class name and create a method with the definition that you want to append in the migration file.

```
partial class MyMigration{
        void MigrationContent(){
                var sqlFile = Path.Combine("Scripts/CustomScript.Sql"); 
                migrationBuilder.Sql(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));
           }
```

Call the Method inside the MyMigration class after where you want to append it.

```
public partial class MyMigration : Migration
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder){}
protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder){}
MigrationContent();
```

Comment: unfortunately that wont work because there are a lot of instances of Migration classes (that would require a lot of additional partial classes) ... "MyMigration" is just an example of 1 instance ... there are over 100 of these files with unique class names and they all need the same 2 lines of text at the bottom. All new instances should aslo automatically get the extra lines when these files are created with "dotnet ef database update --context MyAppContext" .... the goal is to NOT directly write anything into the EF migration file ever.

Comment: bump ... its been 4+ months ... ony 87 views and no actionable answer - is there really no answer to this????

Comment: i found this question while trying to add something to migrations while re-making them over and over. ultimately i went to the Migration class source and made specific partials which override UpOperations/DownOperations properties. but this still requires hand-crafted partial class for each migration. if you think about it, the use case with 100s of them having exactly same extra operation is very niche, that's why there is no ready solution for you. i would probably go with some codegen to create partials for each migration at build time. if you want i can share my class as a base example.