# In efcore 6, Is it possible to generate migration file with table already exists or not condition.( when we run commands) in efcore6

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

In efcore 6, Is it possible to generate migration file with table already exists or not condition.( when we run commands).
Without manually changing in Up method.
I want to get generated code automatically that table exists or not as permy requirements.
Please let me know is it possible by customizing code to generate file.

For references
[How to customize migration generation in EF Core Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575132/how-to-customize-migration-generation-in-ef-core-code-first/63793227#63793227)

Comment: So, you already have a model, and one or more migrations, and you want to update your model and create a migration to match an existing database?

Comment: I have table in database which already having data.

Comment: I have table in database which already having data. I got requirement on going forward this is microservice owned table but don't delete existing table/ table data. I have created model for that table with same details. Now I crwated new migration with command add-migration . It generated create table which says already exists in db. So I want migration file with if table exists ignore else create it. For now I'm doing modelbuilder.sql and executing script in up method manual modification. But I want to any other alternative with out manual changes. @JonasH

Comment: If you are using code first you should let EF create the table, and do any migrations. There is no way to achieve what you want in a reliable and reproducible way.